# Как отследить переключение на другой элемент

Tags: java, javafx

Каким слушателем воспользоваться и есть ли такой, который сработает в тот момент, когда пользователь переключится на другой элемент? Это нужно для того, чтобы проверить корректность ввода текста в поле TextField, по окончанию ввода. Сейчас метод проверки и оповещения об ошибке срабатывает тогда, когда пользователь убирает курсор с TextField. Выскакивает по многу раз, если проводить курсор уже после полученного оповещения, что немного мешает. Можно конечно сделать костыль, но если есть другое решение этой задачи, то не хотелось бы :) Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну в FX есть событие на изменение этого состояния. То есть оно срабатывает И при выделении, И при снятии выделения.

```
TextField yourTextField = new TextField();
yourTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
    {
        if (newPropertyValue)
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
        }
    }
});
```

Пример кода в наглую слямзил [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus)

Comment: Просто приложу документацию по Node.FocuaedProperty: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.FocusedProperty.html